# How do we authenticate users in mobile apps for Android and iPhone?

Tags: php, android, iphone, yii

We are developing a mobile app in Android and iPhone which has a server-side coding in PHP (YII). I want to perform session management on the device for authenticating users in a similar way a website (web browser) could manage. Is there any way I could do session management on the device? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are stored in Server Buffer unlike Cookies.

You should be fine as you do it the same way you would do for any website.

Did you try doing this before asking?

Comment: no i have not tried, i'm confuse, i know the website session management, i'm worried about device session management

Comment: The basic difference between session and cookies is: Cookies are stored in "browser" and sessions are not!
So, considering what I said above... Go ahead with the coding stuff as you would do for any website because, sessions are stored on your SERVER and not on the device so irrespective, you have what you want to do ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about iphone, but android offers persisten storage in preferences - you can store there some access token and authenticate them against  your service.   Then on every request this token shall be passed together with request dat and your service can evaluate this token
to authentificate and authorise request.

But basically it is not a good idea to store sensitive security information  on device - there are nice frameworks like **OAuth**  which will allow you to  give access to service without
storing sensitive security credentials on device and also provide ways to revoke access to particular devices in case they are compromissed.

Comment: basically i am using yii php framework for server side coding, do you have any idea about Yii framework which can support this session mangement for devices.?, also i would like to know about frameworks OAuth,

Comment: just google up on OAuth  - there are a lot of tutorials etc.    This is hoq QYPE doing this: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Authenticating Users in Mobile Apps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps). You can either use a web browser (through WebViews) on the mobile device, or issue an authentication token to the app.